# How do I open my Swift app with a URL and pass data?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, url, swift, uri

I am trying to get my app to be able to capture the url that launched it, and parse the passed values.

Here is how it is done in ObjC

```
- (void)handleGetURLEvent:(NSAppleEventDescriptor *)event withReplyEvent:(NSAppleEventDescriptor *)replyEvent
{
  [event paramDescriptorForKeyword:keyDirectObject] ;

   NSString *urlStr = [[event paramDescriptorForKeyword:keyDirectObject] stringValue];
     // Now you can parse the URL and perform whatever action is needed
   NSLog(@"URL: %@", urlStr);
}
```

What I have so far is ..

```
func handleGetURLEvent(event: NSAppleEventDescriptor?, replyEvent: NSAppleEventDescriptor?) {

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a few days scouring the web ... I found this solution.

```
func applicationWillFinishLaunching(notification: NSNotification?) {

    // -- launch the app with url
    NSAppleEventManager.sharedAppleEventManager().setEventHandler(self, andSelector: Selector("handleGetURLEvent:withReplyEvent:"), forEventClass: AEEventClass(kInternetEventClass), andEventID: AEEventID(kAEGetURL))
}

func handleGetURLEvent(event: NSAppleEventDescriptor!, withReplyEvent: NSAppleEventDescriptor!) {
    let urlPassed = NSURL(string: event.paramDescriptorForKeyword(AEKeyword(keyDirectObject))!.stringValue!)
    println(urlPassed)
}
```

I had 2 issues in my code. Firstly my selector did not match the function name for getting the url (handleGetURLEvent). The second issue was the finding the correct placement of exclamation points for unwrapping the optionals.

Hopes this helps you out if you had the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you need

```
func handleGetURLEvent(event: NSAppleEventDescriptor?, replyEvent: NSAppleEventDescriptor?) {
    if let aeEventDescriptor = event?.paramDescriptorForKeyword(AEKeyword(keyDirectObject)) {
        let urlStr = aeEventDescriptor.stringValue
        println(urlStr)
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting an error: 'Int' is not convertible to 'AEKeyword'

Comment: I'm getting this same error. @BrianPeters Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: hopefully it's working correctly for you now, @CliftonLabrum